# How to restrict grep to search only the one column within a CSV file, but to output matching lines in their entirety?

Tags: csv, grep

How can I use `grep` to search only one column within a CSV file, but after a match is found, to output the entire line? E.g.:

```
fish @ eats worms
bear @ eats fish
```

Searching for `fish` in column 2 will output: `bear @ eats fish`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

...Use awk...

```
awk -F@ '{if ($2 ~ /fish/) { print $0; }}' <input file>
```

To use a shell variable change single quotes to doubles and escape the awk variables (soo awk still sees $2 etc and not the shell's expansion of them.

```
awk -F@ "{if (\$2 ~ /$find_me/ ) { print \$0; } }" <input_file>
```

Comment: If I want to use a BASH variable, instead of "fish", why does `awk -F@ '{if ($2 ~ /$variable/) { print $0; }}' file.csv` fail to work?

Comment: single quotes around the awk program stop the shell from expanding the variable. You can change to double quotes, but you'll need to escape the $2 and $0

Comment: Liked `awk -F@ "{if ('$2' ~ /'$variable'/) { print '$0'; }}" file.csv`?

Comment: That might work (but don't single quote $variable - you do want that expanded). I know the one in the edited answer does work.

Comment: The one in the edited answer does not work, I just get `syntax error`.

Comment: Sorry, it's missing a ) - try again.

Answer (score -1):

Using `grep`:

```
grep ^.*@.*fish.*$ file.txt
```

Comment: can you explain what this does ?