# How to use awk to search for a complete match of text within one column of a CSV file and to only output the first matching line?

Tags: csv, awk

I am using the answer from [How to restrict grep to search only the one column within a CSV file, but to output matching lines in their entirety?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118468/how-to-restrict-grep-to-search-only-the-one-column-within-a-csv-file-but-to-out) to search particular columns with awk, then output matching rows, e.g.:

```
awk -F@ "{if (\$2 ~ /$find_me/ ) { print \$0; } }" <input_file>
```

- How can I restrict the search to only match lines where the column matches `$find_me` entirely?
- How can I restrict the search to only output the first match found in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
awk -F@ -v pattern="$find_me" '$2 ~ "^" pattern "$"' input.txt
```

Or

```
awk -F@ -v pattern="^$find_me\$" '$2 ~ pattern' input.txt
```

Comment: It is working when I replace `$fine_me` with some text, but not when `$fine_me` is used.

Comment: @Village: Make sure you're using the proper quotation marks as shown in kev's answer. Also, to only print the first match, use `awk -F@ -v pattern="$find_me" '$2 ~ "^" pattern "$" {print; exit}' input.txt`